# PHP MVC Login form action='?'

Tags: php, authentication

I am very new to programming and trying to build my own MVC project in php.

My folder structure:
[image: folder structure]

My router looks like this:

```
class App 
{
    protected $controller = 'index'; // Default controller

    protected $method = 'index'; // Default method

    protected $params = []; // Default parameters are an empty array

    public function __construct()
    {
        Sessions::start_session(); // Start a session, logged in or not?

        $url = $this->parseUrl();

        if (file_exists('controllers/controller.' . $url[0] . '.php')) 
        {
            $this->controller = $url[0];
            unset($url[0]);
        } 

        require_once 'controllers/controller.' . $this->controller . '.php';

        $this->controller = new $this->controller;

        if(isset($url[1])) 
        {
            if(method_exists($this->controller, $url[1])) 
            {
                $this->method = $url[1];
                unset($url[1]);
            }
        }

        $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

        call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);
    }

    public function parseUrl()
    {
        if(isset($_GET['url'])) 
        {
            return $url = explode('/',filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    }
}
```

My login controller looks like this:

```
class login extends Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->render('login/index');
    }

    public function login_user()
    {
        $this->model('login');
        $this->model->log_user($_POST['email'], md5($_POST['password']));
    }
}
```

My login view looks like this:

```
<form action='????' method='post' id='loginForm' onSubmit='return false;'>
                <div class='inputField'>
                    <input type='email' name='email'  id='email' placeholder='Email' autofocus />
                </div>
                <div class='inputField'>
                    <input type='password' name='password' id='password' placeholder='Password' />
                </div>
                <div class='inputField'>
                    <input type='submit' name='submiter' value='Login' />
```

Now **my question** is how can I call the login_user method in the Login class from the form's action attribute in the login view?

Help would be highly appreciated! If I should post any other code snippets, please let me know.

Comment: Did you already give a try to something like `action="login/login_user"` or `action="<?=URL; ?>login/login_user"` (where `URL` is the path to correctly point you to the controller)? If your routing class is well written, it should work in a way similar to one of those two.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried both of these things and to my surprise neither worked. That is why I posted my problem here!

Comment: I tried this: action='<?php APP_PATH ?>login/login_user' but nothing even happens, if I click the login button...

Comment: You are not putting an `echo` there. `<?php echo APP_PATH; ?>`. Otherwise: `<?=APP_PATH; ?>`.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Unfortunately that does not solve the problem. But thank you very much for your efforts!

Comment: define('APP_PATH', '/mvc-project/'); <form action='<?php echo APP_PATH ?>login/login_user'

Comment: Take a look at [here](https://github.com/panique/php-login/blob/master/application/libs/Application.php). Routing class with correct url parsing. It works, I'm using it for some projects.

Comment: Great! Thank you! I will have a look there!!